# How do I find the milliseconds of a certain time?

Tags: java, timer, milliseconds

I have a program that I would like to run at 9:00 PM my computer time. I need a way to find the milliseconds of that so that I can make the computer loop until it hits it. Something like this:

```
while(true){
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() == [insert method to find millis].[get](2100)){
         break;
    }
}
// Do stuff
```

So I just need a way to get those Millis from 9 PM. Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, please answer as soon as possible... 9 is in 10 minutes

Comment: What if the computer is busy by another process at 09:00:00 and your loop is only tested at 09:00:01?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object ([`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is most probable) and use [`getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29).

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 12, 18, 21, 0, 0);
if(System.currentTimeMillis() == cal.getTimeInMillis()){

}
```

It should be noted that if you want to do this regularly, you might want to look at a scheduled task instead.

Comment: So is this in 24 hr or am/pm? Because I don't see an option for that.

Comment: Maybe `17` as OP wants it for tonight?

Comment: 24 hour clock, as it should. Your 9PM threw me off, use 24h notation.

Comment: @peeskillet: 21, not 17 ;)

Comment: oh, gotcha. It's day 18 in my timezone, he'll have to change it to whatever day he wants it.

Comment: If 9 is in 10 minutes as OP stated, its still the 17th for him

Comment: Keep in mind the chances of this line being called at exactly 9PM (down to the millisecond) are tiny.  You should really check if the current time is within a range.

Comment: I agree with @NathanielJones: either check for a range or use a flag.

Comment: @NathanielJones, thanks, that helps. Maybe a %10 or something?